# Assigning edge weight to an igraph object in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have a co-occurrence matrix that I want to convert to an igraph object. The matrix has three columns- `node1`, `node2` and `freq`.

I have created the graph using the `graph_from_edgelist` command.

```
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(coOccurDf[1:n,1:2]), directed=F)
```

I now need to assign weights to the edges. I've tried to use two functions, which both seem to do the same job, but to no avail.

```
set.edge.attribute(g, "weight", index=E(g), coOccurDf[1:n,]$freq)
```

and

```
set_edge_attr(g, "weight", index=E(g), coOccurDf[1:n,]$freq)
```

Neither of these two commands throws an error, but when I try to see the weights using

```
E(g)$weight
```

It just displays `NULL`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh silly me. I thought it modified the original while at it. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it! Thanks.

Comment: By the way, it is much cleaner to write `E(g)$weight <- whatever` instead of using `set_edge_attr`.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the weights of an `igraph` object as follows:

```
edge.attributes(g)$weight

E(g)$weight
```

You can set weights of an `igraph` object by assigning to either of these:

```
edge.attributes(g)$weight <- coOccurDf[1:n,]$freq

E(g)$weight <- coOccurDf[1:n,]$freq
```

To use the `set.edge.attribute` function it returns a new graph with weights assigned. To assign it to an object `g` rather than print the weighted graph to the console:

```
g <- set.edge.attribute(g, "weight", index=E(g), coOccurDf[1:n,]$freq)
```